# TikZ: Expand width of each picture to given size

Tags: tikz-pgf, two-column, bounding-box

I create plots with `pgf`/`TikZ`, externalize them and then they will be included into another predefined LaTeX-document (which someone else will do, so I can't change anything there). That final document has a two-column layout and all images will be scaled to a width of 80mm (= 1 column width).

When I create a `TikZ`-picture and externalize it, the resulting pdf is nicely cropped. However, in my case I need all my pictures to have a width of exactly 80mm. I do not want to scale the pictures, but center each of them on a 80mm-wide canvas.

I came up with a solution using the bounding box of the current picture and enlarging it to my needs. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color,pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,external}
\tikzexternalize

% define column size (= image width)
\newlength{\singlecol}
\setlength{\singlecol}{80mm}

% set bounding box for each picture, i.e. expand to image width/column size
\tikzset{singpic/.append style={
   execute at end picture={
    \coordinate (BBCorner1) at ($ (current bounding box.south) + (-0.5*\singlecol,0) $);
    \coordinate (BBCorner4) at ($ (current bounding box.north) + (0.5*\singlecol,0) $);
    \path[use as bounding box, draw, blue] (BBCorner1) rectangle (BBCorner4);
    }
   }
}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[singpic]
      \filldraw[fill=yellow!20] (0,0) rectangle (5,5) node[midway] {The Picture};
      \draw[red, thick] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

So this works as it should, but is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Thanks so much for posting a compilable example.

Comment: Have you considered leaving the images as small as they are and just center them within the column by using `\centering` or a `center` environment?

Comment: Well, I would love to do just that, but that means I would need to change the include-picture-environment in the final two-column LaTeX-document, right? Unfortunately I don't have any influence on that part, so I need a solution for my pictures to have the correct size.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that's quite a good approach. Minor suggestions for simplifying the code:

The effect of `[use as bounding box]` is to fix the bounding box at the size it has after the path you supply the option to, so any paths specified later on will not increase the bounding box further. Since you specify the path at the very end of the picture, the option has no effect in this case. Note that `[use as bounding box]` does not decrease the bounding box size. In case you want the bounding box of the picture to match the bounding box of the path in all cases, you have to issue `\pgfresetboundingbox` first.

Also, you don't have to define the coordinates first and then define a rectangle between them to get the correct bounding box. Instead, you can just specify a path between the two points directly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} % TikZ loads PGF and color automatically
\usetikzlibrary{calc,external}

% define column size (= image width)
\newlength{\singlecol}
\setlength{\singlecol}{80mm}

% set bounding box for each picture, i.e. expand to image width/column size
\tikzset{
    singpic/.append style={
        execute at end picture={
            \path [draw] ($ (current bounding box.south) + (-0.5*\singlecol,0) $) -- +(\singlecol,0);
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[singpic]
      \filldraw[fill=yellow!20] (0,0) rectangle (5,5) node[midway] {The Picture};
      \draw[red, thick] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanations! The height of each picture shall not be fixed, but adjusted to its contents. Therefore I've put the `[use as bounding box]` path at the very end, so I can use and keep the current height of each individual picture. True, I can't decrease the bounding box (which would mean to crop away some of the picture's contents), so I probably should think about some way to ensure that my pictures are never to big (or trigger a warning in such a case), but I guess that's a different question ...

Comment: Ah, just understood now - since I draw the bounding box path at the end, I can omit the option `[use as bounding box]`. The bounding box will be adjusted automatically to that path anyway (if the path is the largest object).

Comment: Yup, that's what I meant. Sorry for not being clearer. You might want to edit your question (or ask a new one) about generating a warning if your picture is too big, that's definitely an interesting question.

Comment: No problem, I'm still quite new to TikZ/pgf, so I need some time to understand. I'll do some research on the picture-too-big-problem before posting a new question.

Comment: You mentioned that I won't need to define the coordinates of my path first. But then in your case the `(current bounding box)` will somehow be updated while drawing the path which results in more space on the left side than on the right. I've attached a picture to your post to show what I mean.

Comment: Just realized that life is much simpler: using the desired width and relative coordinates for the 2. point does the trick already: `\path[draw,blue] ($ (current bounding box.center) + (-0.5*\singlecol,0) $) -- +(\singlecol,0);`

Comment: @Kristin: You're right! I've changed the code in my answer accordingly.